# Selecting Multiple Thumnail Images issue in Bootply 79859

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using bootstrap carousel which is created with thumnail images. I got the sample from http://bootply.com/79859 The difference from the sample i got is the number of thumnails. Mines are more than ten. The problem when I select second thumnail it also selects all thumnails which has carousel-select-id over "9". I think it is because jquery confuse at some point. "select" is added to carousel-selector-1 and carousel-selector-10, carousel-selector-11...

Here is a jsfiddle link which is created someone else but with the same issue.   http://jsfiddle.net/xuhP9/21/

I have tried to add a if control but it did not give the complete solution as I want

Can someone solve that problem?

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {   

     var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
     id = parseInt(id);
     if(id==1){
      //alert("id=1");
      id=1;
      $('carousel-selector-1').addClass('selected');
     }
     else{
          $('carousel-selector-1').removeClass('selected');

     $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
     $('#left_id').text("left-id" + id+ " pixels");
     $('[id^=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector in the last line in your code:

```
$('[id=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');}`
```

Comment: I tried but that doesnt work selected class indicates the selected thumnails.It is not logical to remove that row.

Comment: It works in [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xuhP9/82/) indeed. Note I wrote "remove the _starts with_ selector", not "remove the whole row".